# How to reference NSPredicate's "%@" for segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a NSPredicate similar to the one [How To Implement Search Bar in iOS 7 Using Storyboard](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/):

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText]; 
    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]; 
}
```

I'm trying to grab the `%@` to pass it on to my next view using `self.searchText`;

but that doesn't seem to work.

How to reference NSPredicate's `%@` for segue?

segue:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Twotwo"]) {

    Two *two2 = [segue destinationViewController];
    two2.searchText = self.searchText;`
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
    _searchText=self.searchText;
```

edit:

My goal, basically, is to get the searchText string from TestViewController to pass to Two on segue.

**TestViewController.h**

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *searchText;
```

**TestViewController.m**

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(one beginswith[c] %@) OR (two beginswith[c] %@) OR (three beginswith[c] %@)", searchText, searchText, searchText];
    searchResults = [cdh filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]; }
```

**Two.h**

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *searchText;
```

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't seem to work?  Do you have any code to share?

Comment: what is mean by predicate for segues.

Comment: @AnkitThakur what i mean is, I have a predicate search term that I want to pass to my next view.

Comment: Have you verified that `self.searchText` is not `nil` when you assign it to `two2.searchText`?

Comment: @Avi haha you are right, it's totally null. so how do i reference (NSString*)searchText out of the - (void)filterContentForSearchText?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to learn the basics of programming before asking questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the predicate at all, and mentioning it in the question has everyone confused. It seems you already have a property to store the search term you want to use, you just aren't updating it.nyou should have:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    self.searchText = searchText;
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText]; 
    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]; 
}
```

And it looks like you can remove the line in `viewDidLoad` (which again it looks like you're confused as you're direct accessing the memory for the instance variable and setting it to the value returned by the getter for the same instance variable...)

Comment: I, actually, want to grab my (NSString*)searchText and segue it to my next screen. the viewDidLoad was for view2.

Comment: @user3306356 so just grab it

Comment: @Andy I'm getting property 'searchText' not found on object of type 'ViewController*'....

Comment: @user3306356 add property and update it as Wain suggested

Comment: @andy it's null when i pass it but fine in it's "void"

Comment: You'll need to explain the view controllers names and show what properties they each have

Comment: property: @property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *searchText; &&&& segue         NSLog(@"%@", _searchText);
        Two *two2 = [segue destinationViewController];
        two2.searchText = [self searchText];

Comment: - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
     NSLog(@"%@", searchText); --- this echo works perfectly --- echo in segue is null

Comment: @Wain any ideas? I've tried @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *searchText; but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Show the header of both view controllers in your question, code in comments isn't readable, and explain which one is which

Comment: @Wain please look at edits, thanks.

Comment: so you haven't actually added the code in my answer? because it looks like that's all you need to do...

Comment: @Wain seems everything is okay. How do I get the searchText to display automatically in the search bar? I thought the viewDidLoad `    _searchText=self.searchText;` might do it but it doesn't.

Comment: that's a different question, and this one is confusing enough without added complexity. i thought that text came from the search bar anyway? when you ask that new question be sure to explain the details of the view controller, how it's shown and when the text should be added to the search bar (indeed why it should be added to the search bar at all)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116361/discussion-between-user3306356-and-wain).